# While merging code I got some conflict error in bitbucket

Tags: git, liferay, bitbucket

While merging code in GIT (Bitbucket), I got an issue `src/main/webapp/css/main.css` (conflicts)
the code is fine in Eclipse but in Bitbucket view its showing 2 more lines added in code having some text. like

`<<<<<<< destination:f27cd37fb7008c0d18f63514ca44ceacbaa3c658`

and

`>>>>>>> source:95de515e0203585db3c4f1084e37ade6dcc08ed2`

Comment: What if you open the file with notepad or something?

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for the reply... yeap in text-editor code is fine.. but in bitbicket code viewer its displaying 2 more lines :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a backup of your changes
2. Override and update (or Revert) your local file with the latest on
   Git
3. Apply your changes again
4. Try to commit and push

Comment: nope bro its not working, displaying this error "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart."